# TypeError: draw_row() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given) on line 55

Tags: python, python-turtle

i have a homework due Friday but i have a question and my teacher isn't replying to me so can you help me please?

i just started python turtle at school and this is the code i wrote

```
from turtle import*

def square(square_color, length):
  pd()
  color(square_color)
  begin_fill
  for i in range(4):
    fd(length)
    lt(90)
  end_fill()
  pu()
  fd(length)

speed(0)
n= int(input("Enter a number:"))
pu()
bk(n*25)
pu()
bk(n*25)

for cur_square in range(n):
  if cur_square % 2 ==0:
    square("black", 50)
  if cur_square % 2 ==1:
    square("red", 50)
  if cur_square % 2 ==2:
    square("gray", 50)

def draw_row(rows, length, square1_color, square2_color, cur_square):
  for i in range(rows):
    if(cur_square + i)% 2 ==0:
      square(square1_color, length)
    if (cur_square + i )%2 ==1:
      square(square2_color, length)


def move_up(rows, length):
  lt(90)
  fd(length)
  rt(90)
  bk(rows*length)


length = int(input("The length of one square: "))
rows = int(input("The total amount of rows:"))
color1 = input("Color of the first square:")
color2 = input("Color of the second square:")
color3 = input("Color of the third square:")

speed(0)
pu()
setpos(-rows/2 * length, -rows/2 * length)

for cur_square in range(rows):
  draw_row(rows, length, color1, color2, color3, cur_square)
  move_up(rows,length)
```

it tells me that i have an error  - *TypeError: draw_row() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given) on line 55*

what should I do?

the exact line i have error with

```
for cur_square in range(rows):
      draw_row(rows, length, color1, color2, color3, cur_square)
      move_up(rows,length)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear, you defined `draw_row()` to take five arguments:

```
def draw_row(rows, length, square1_color, square2_color, cur_square):
```

And then when it came time to call it, you passed six:

```
draw_row(rows, length, color1, color2, color3, cur_square)
```

As defined, `draw_row()` only deals with two colors, `square1_color` and `square2_color`:

```
def draw_row(rows, length, square1_color, square2_color, cur_square):
    for i in range(rows):
        if (cur_square + i) % 2 == 0:
            square(square1_color, length)
        else:
            square(square2_color, length)
```

but when you called it, you passed in three different colors, `color1`, `color2`, and `color3`.